# Determine extension when downloading a file with curl?

Tags: c++, curl

I've created a program that downloads subtitles from INTERNET using curl
How to know the extension of the file I downloaded (.zip or .rar)?

here is my code (it is a part of function)

```
FILE* download=fopen("download.zip","wb");//i assume it's a zip
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,post_data.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write2file);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, download);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
if(res != CURLE_OK)
    std::cout<<"Download Failed "<<std::endl;
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
fclose(download);
```

Comment: The file extension is whatever the server says it is. Not something you can easily control. Instead, you should check the mime type of the result.

Comment: I've tried that by getting the header then parsing it but by then the file would have been written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`curl_easy_getinfo()`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) function, it has the content-type info:

> CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE
>
> Pass a pointer to a char pointer to receive the content-type of the
>   downloaded object. This is the value read from the Content-Type:
>   field. If you get NULL, it means that the server didn't send a valid
>   Content-Type header or that the protocol used doesn't support this.

Using the info you can give the right extension to the downloaded file by renaming it on disk.

Comment: I've tried that too and also tried parsing the headers my self but by then I would have already written the file assuming it's a zip

Comment: not a Curl user, but can't you run this function without using `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` and/or `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, this would give you the info without writing file. Or you can rename file on disk after download.